# PHP Laravel MongoDB SCRAM Failure: invalid salt length of 16 in sasl step2

Tags: mongodb, sasl-scram

Hoping you are doing great.

We are recently trying to migrate to Azure Cosmos and facing the following issue while trying to connect our Laravel Application with Mongodb. Connection with Studio 3T works fine.

Connection URI:

mongodb+srv://user@test.mongocluster.cosmos.azure.com/?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000

[image: PHP Mongodb Driver]

[image: Laravel error]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm encountering the same issue and raised a SR on Microsoft.
They confirmed this to be a bug:

> I am writing to inform you that I have checked with our product team, and they have confirmed the presence of a bug in connecting  vCore MongoDB for CosmosDB cluster with Mongo PHP driver.
> [...]
> there is currently no ETA available

Comment: @BlueSpider I disagree; it answers the question by informing the questioner that the behaviour they are experiencing is seemingly the result of a bug on Microsoft's end, which I'm also experienced using the C driver with mongo_fdw for PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Microsoft is sending a salt appropriate to SHA-1 when it should be longer for SHA-256](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mongo_fdw/issues/174#issuecomment-1862765893).

SHA-1 has a 160-bit = [20 byte](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/3a624d53dfed8820019a8fb0e436f6151588f0f5/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.c#L120) length, but [apparently the last four are replaced with 0x1](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/3a624d53dfed8820019a8fb0e436f6151588f0f5/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.c#L648) so 16 is the appropriate length of the decoded salt. SHA-256 is 256-bit = 32 bytes, 32 - 4 = 28 bytes should be received. [The Mongo driver checks for this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/3a624d53dfed8820019a8fb0e436f6151588f0f5/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-scram.c#L823) and errors out if the user salt is of an incorrect size.